# Get PKCS#8 key from .jks storage

Tags: applications, apk, signature-error

Previously I used **jarsigner** tool for APK signatures.
But jarsigner provides v.1 sign only.

So, I'm trying to move signing process to **apksigner** because I need v.2 signature as well.
And it works well when I use .jks for it.
Please, check example below.

```
  apksigner sign \
     --ks some.jks \
     --ks-pass pass:somepass \
     --v1-signing-enabled true \
     --v2-signing-enabled true \
     --v3-signing-enabled true \
     --v4-signing-enabled false \
     --out DESTINATION_APP \
     PATH_TO_APK
```

Also I need option to sign APK with key and cert parameters.
I've tried to use my .key and .crt file from .jks storage but it returns me an error.
[image]

According to the documentation key file must be in **PKCS#8** format and cert in **X.509**.
Could you please tell me how can I export .key and .crt in correct formats?

Thanks.

Comment: @Robert, I've removed post from there. It was added to Serverfauld mistakenly.

Comment: I would try to open the JKS file using https://keystore-explorer.org and then export the private key using context menu.